# Hadoop Connection Refused Error

Tags: java, hadoop, connection

I was trying to install RMR (RHadoop) package and I somehow managed to mess up my hadoop setup. Now, it gives the connection refused error which I just can't find a solution for. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

```
 java.net.ConnectException: Call to master/***.***.***.***:54310 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1095)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1071)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:225)
at $Proxy2.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:379)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:119)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:238)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:203)
at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:89)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1386)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1404)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:123)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:254)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:574)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:489)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:434)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:560)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2000(Client.java:184)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1202)
at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1046)
... 18 more
```

Comment: Looks like somewhere in your configuration files you need to set the location of the jobtracker or namenode or something.

Comment: The whole thing is totally messed up. I fix one error, subsequently several other errors pop up. Now, the namenode won't start. Guess I have to erase and reinstall completely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you see this, it basically means that you are unable to connected to the NameNode. It's either not running or running on a different port. If you backed up your working *-site.xml files, you may be able go back to the working version without the complete re-install you sugges in the comment to your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have struggled two days and the night between to find out the answer to this problem.

In my case( and I'm sure this is the problem in most cases )  had to create the hadoop temporary folder by hand and add them to the hdfs-site.xml !

```
<property>
<name>dfs.data.dir</name>
<value>/home/stefan/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.1/tmp/dfs/name/data</value>
<final>true</final> 
</property> 
<property> 
<name>dfs.name.dir</name>
<value>/home/stefan/Downloads/hadoop-2.7.1/tmp/dfs/name</value> 
<final>true</final> 
</property>
```

I hope this helps you guys not to go through the same hell as me.

Besides that

```
chown user_name hadoop_folder hadoop_temp_folder
chmod 755 hadoop_folder hadoop_temp_folder
```